# Induction Mathematics and Factorials

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, factorial

\usepackage{amsmath}

Evaluate the sum

$\sum_{k=1}^{n} {k\over (k+1)!}$

$\sum_{k=1}^{1} {1\over (1+1)!} = {1\over 2}$

$\sum_{k=1}^{2} {2\over (2+1)!} = {5\over 6}$

$\sum_{k=1}^{3} {3\over (3+1)!} = {23\over 24}$

...

for n = 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.
￼Make a conjecture about a formula for this sum for general n, and prove your conjecture by mathematical induction.

Conjecture: numerator = denominator - 1

${(k+1)!-1\over (k+1)!} = {k!1!-1\over k!1!} = {k!-1 \over k!} = {k-1\over k}$

This makes sense to me but I'm not sure how to go about writing it in a induction proof format. Is this correct at all? Am I on the right path?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your summations following the question are not correct: they should be

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=1}^1\frac{k}{(k+1)!}&=\frac1{(1+1)!}=\frac12\\
\sum_{k=1}^2\frac{k}{(k+1)!}&=\frac1{(1+1)!}+\frac2{(2+1)!}=\frac12+\frac26=\frac56\\
\sum_{k=1}^3\frac{k}{(k+1)!}&=\frac56+\frac3{(3+1)!}=\frac56+\frac3{24}=\frac{23}{24}\\
\sum_{k=1}^4\frac{k}{(k+1)!}&=\frac{23}{24}+\frac4{(4+1)!}=\frac{23}{24}+\frac4{120}=\frac{119}{120}\\
\sum_{k=1}^5\frac{k}{(k+1)!}&=\frac{119}{120}+\frac5{(5+1)!}=\frac{119}{120}+\frac5{720}=\frac{719}{720}\;.
\end{align*}$$

Be careful not to confuse $k$, the index variable, with $n$, the upper limit of the summation.

The conjecture that

$$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}\tag{1}$$

is then very reasonable. However, your attempts to simplify it are completely mistaken: you can easily check that in general $(n+1)!\ne n!1!=n!$ and that $\frac{n!-1}{n!}\ne\frac{n-1}n$.

Your next step should be to prove by induction that $(1)$ is true for all $n\ge 1$.

**Added:** Take $(1)$ as your induction hypothesis; then in the induction step you want to use that hypothesis to prove that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(n+2)!-1}{(n+2)!}\;.\tag{2}$$

Notice that

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{(k+1)!}+\frac{n+1}{(n+2)!}\;;\tag{3}$$

now use $(1)$, your induction hypothesis, to get rid of the summation on the righthand side of $(3)$, and do some algebra to complete the proof of $(2)$.

Comment: when putting in S(1) into 

${(1+1)!-1\over (1+1)!}$ = ${2-1\over 2} = { 1\over 2}$

so then S(k):

${(k+1)!-1\over (k+1)!}$ 

which is my original hypothesis, now do I prove for S(k+1)? and once Im there:

${((k+1)+1)!-1\over ((k+1)+1)!} = {(k+2)!-1 \over (k+2)!}$

I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: @DavidC85: No, your induction hypothesis $S(n)$ should be the statement that $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(n+1)!-1}{(n+1)!}\;.$$ An induction hypothesis has to be a statement: it has to say something, since it must be something that can be true or false. Assuming that equality, in the induction step you’re trying to use it (and some basic algebra) to prove $S(n+1)$, the statement that $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{((n+1)+1)!-1}{((n+1)+1)!}\;.$$

Comment: so then I still end up with:
${k \over (k+1)!}$ = ${(n+2)!-1 \over (n+2)!}$  and am just as confused as how to proceed

Comment: Im really struggling understanding induction unfortunately.

Comment: @DavidC85: You do *not* end up with $$\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(n+2)!-1}{(n+2)!}\;;$$ you end up trying to prove the equality $$\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{k}{(k+1)!}=\frac{(n+2)!-1}{(n+2)!}\;,$$ which is a completely different statement.

Comment: That is the part Im struggling with, going about proving that equality.
Doing a base case for S(1) ends up with both sides being ${1\over 2}$

Comment: @DavidC85: This is a pretty straightforward induction: there is almost certainly at least one example in your text that you could use as a model. I’ve outlined the argument in an addition to my answer; see if you can fill in the details.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23191/discussion-between-davidc85-and-brian-m-scott).

Comment: @DavidC85: I’m not able to spend the time in chat right now; I’m involved in too many other things that can’t wait. I can see, though, that part of the problem is that you really don’t understand summation notation, and another is very weak algebra: the last two lines of your more recent question make no sense at all, I’m afraid. If it’s at all possible, you need to sit down in person with someone who can help you; it looks as if your confusion may be too deep to be sorted out with straightforward questions and answers here.

Comment: This is most likely the case as I have not used my math in almost 10 years.  I thank you for your time and patience none-the-less.